# Why is my css animation code not working in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

This code used to work fine in Google Chrome last time but now it doesn't work anymore. The bars will fill up by a solid colour animating (2 seconds) in when you scroll it in view.
Internet Explorer works fine.
Any help, please? I've tried looking around but to no avail.

```
.levelPM {
    height:     25px; /* IE CSS Variables Fallback */
    height:     var(--bar-h);
    width:      0px;
    background: #7ae89f; /* IE CSS Variables Fallback */
    background: var(--projectmanage-col);
}

.projectmanage.start {
    -webkit-animation: projectmanage 2s ease-out forwards;
       -moz-animation: projectmanage 2s ease-out forwards;
         -o-animation: projectmanage 2s ease-out forwards;
            animation: projectmanage 2s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes projectmanage {
    0%   { width: 0px; }
    100% { width: 90%; /* IE CSS Variables Fallback */ width: var(--projectmanage-perc); }
}

@-moz-keyframes projectmanage {
    0%   { width: 0px; }
    100% { width: 90%; /* IE CSS Variables Fallback */ width: var(--projectmanage-perc); }
}

@-o-keyframes projectmanage {
    0%   { width: 0px; }
    100% { width: 90%; /* IE CSS Variables Fallback */ width: var(--projectmanage-perc); }
}

@keyframes projectmanage {
    0%   { width: 0px; }
    100% { width: 90%; /* IE CSS Variables Fallback */ width: var(--projectmanage-perc); }
}
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/TegPh7pf

Comment: please show us html

Comment: @לבנימלכה I've added a pastebin link.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will not trigger the scroll if the page has no scroll, use "bind (wheel)" instead.

```
$(window).bind("wheel", function() {
  console.log("asdads")
    checkAnimation2();
});
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/dobladov/pen/aXZpNP

Comment: Sadly, I'm trying to add this into my Squarespace code block but it does not work.

Comment: In the codepen.io, yes. But adding it here won't work too: https://jsfiddle.net/yLv015p3/. Squarespace code block doesn't divide into 3 individual blocks (html, css, js) so I have to put everything in one.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being in the same file, the problem is that you are not loading JQuery, here is working all in the same file. https://jsfiddle.net/g6pdyzk2/

Comment: Ok, thank you. It works. Just that it stops working due to conflicts with other codes on the page. Decided to drop the animation.

Comment: I'm glad you could fix it!